# Wiring help for Generalaire humidifier

Tags: wiring, humidifier

I’m installing a Generalaire 1042 drip humidifier. The wiring instructions aren’t that clear/detailed.

The thermostat is MHX3C. It has connections C, NC and NO.

The furnace is a Keeprite C9MPD075F12B1.
The furnace has the standard R, G, Y, W, C connections.

I’m trying do the wiring between the humidistat and solenoid and furnace.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks.

Note: I’ve given up (I normally don’t so easily, but for reason I’m not into it this time), so I’m going to have someone come in a do the work for me.

Furnace circuit board:
[image]
[image]
Humidistat:
[image]
Furnace wiring diagram:
[image]

Comment: The pics are great! Are we to presume that the first is the board of the humidifier and the second is the furnace?

Comment: Both are from the circuit board on the furnace. I’ll post a humidistat pic in a moment.

Comment: Thanks. Always good to put a text label above or below the pics so people know what they're looking at.

Comment: Are you stuck with that particular thermostat? It sounds like it's not really designed for the application at hand...

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. I’ve decided to back out of DIYing this. I’ll have someone come in to do the. I know it will be a simple hookup once the wiring is confirmed but id rather have someone else responsible for burning up the furnace circuit board!! I’ll close the question....once I figure out how to do it!

Comment: Those wires should all have proper clockwise hooks on them, under the screw heads. They're not secure as they are.

Answer (score 1):

Generalaire products are not very DIY friendly. In the rare event someone has a similar problem I'm posting this. The diagram is for your model humidifier and humidistat. The hard part for a DIY'er is finding the right terminals on the furnace board. Since you posted the wiring diagram for the board someone more knowledgeable than me could figure it out in two minutes and determine which terminals to use on the board. [image: Wiring Diagram]